# Payments in booking system

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am trying to figure out how I can use Paypal to process payments in a booking system I am building. I think Paypal has a very messy documentation, and I can't seem to get a good overview over what to do. Firstly, I'm from Norway, and it seems Paypal has some restrictions when it comes to what kind of solution I can choose. These two are the ones that seem in the right corner:

- Website Payments Standard
- Express Checkout

What I generally wants is to send the user to paypal. If the payment is confirmed, the user should be sent to a confirmation page. As I understand it, that won't be a problem. But how can my system know that the payment is okay? Is there any id being sent back and forth? The system needs to save some information about the payment in the database.

What solution should I choose?
And how can I associate the payment with the current booking?

Answer (score 1):

Paypal sends response "Verified" for successful payments when you use ipn_url, using this response you can check if the payment is ok or not.
For more info pls check the link:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro

For Codeigniter you can use paypal library: this might be of help:
https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn